# помощь с счетчиком

Tags: javascript

```
let counter = 0;
  
const counterValue = document.getElementById('counter-value');
const incrementBtn = document.getElementById('increment-btn');
const decrementBtn = document.getElementById('decrement-btn');
  
// To increment the value of counter
incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter++;
    counterValue.innerHTML = counter;
});
  
// To decrement the value of counter
decrementBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter--;
    counterValue.innerHTML = counter;
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при counter меньше или равен 0 кнопка декремента его не уменьшала а оставляла на нуле?

Еще хочу сделать привязку этого счетчика к стоимости товара. То есть, если на счетчике 1, то цена 100 рублей, если на счетчике 3, то цена 300. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну прочитайте про `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter++;
    counterValue.innerHTML = counter;
    updatePrice();
});

decrementBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        counterValue.innerHTML = counter;
        updatePrice();
    }
});

function updatePrice() {
    let price;
    if (counter === 1) {
        price = 100;
    } else if (counter === 3) {
        price = 300;
    } else {
        // Добавьте дополнительные условия для других значений counter, если требуется
        price = 0; // Значение по умолчанию, если нет совпадений
    }
    // Обновите элемент с отображением стоимости товара
    const priceElement = document.getElementById('price');
    priceElement.innerHTML = price + ' рублей';
}
```

Comment: Что это за бред? Не ужели не понятна логика, как расчитать цену?

Comment: типичный русский быдлан, вместо даже такого банального ответа как у меня просто что то высрал в коментах.

Comment: Включайте мозг..